# how to get all the incoming connections in linux

Tags: linux, connection, netstat

netstat lists all the connections (incoming and outgoing)
how do I filter out just the incoming connections

I have tried the netstat command but it lists all the connections but j need only the incoming connections

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You could check if there is a process listening at the same local port and assume that all conections using the same local port are *probably* incoming. For example if there is a web server listening at port 80 you can assume that all connections with local port 80 are probably incoming. (There might be a way to create a script to automate this.)

Answer (score 0):

Once sockets are created, there isn't really such thing as inbound and outbound, as connections go both ways. What you really care about are connections you started, vs connections others started. To do that, you have to monitor for new connections, and log them as they are created.

`tcpdump` is a great tool for this. There are tons of guides on the internet, but a command to get you started would be `tcpdump -Qin ...`.

Answer (score 0):

With `netstat` you may identify the state of the socket, but in many cases there are no states in raw mode and usually no states used in UDP and UDPLite. You may try to display the listening state for incoming connections by running `netstat` with the following argument:

```
netstat --listening
```

However, as far as I understood from your question it is better to use the `tcpdump` tool as mentioned in other comments.